# Trying to understand reduce using an object as previousValue

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to js, trying to replace a for loop with reduce and am having trouble.

As I understand it, `||` only evaluates the left operand. If it's truthy, it's passed as the value. If it's falsy, the right operand is passed without being evaluated, because it's the deciding factor.

For some reason this works in the for loop, but not in reduce. Shouldn't its inability to read `obj[val]` or `obj[arr[ind]]` make it return `0 + 1` on the first iteration?

```
'use strict';

let strings = ["One", "Two", "Two", "Three", "Three", "Three"];

let findMostCommon = (arr) => {
    let str;
    let obj;
    let keys;
    let counter;

    str = "";
    obj = {};
    counter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log(arr[i]); // One, Two, Two, Three, etc.
        obj[arr[i]] = (obj[arr[i]] || 0) + 1; // Works
    }

/*
    arr.reduce((obj, val, ind, arr) => {
        obj[val] = (obj[val] || 0) + 1;
    }, obj) 

    obj[val] = (obj[val] || 0) + 1;
                   ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'Two' of undefined
*/

/* 
    arr.reduce((obj, val, ind, arr) => {
        obj[arr[ind]] = (obj[arr[ind]] || 0) + 1;
    }, obj)

    obj[arr[ind]] = (obj[arr[ind]] || 0) + 1;
                        ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'Two' of undefined
*/

    keys = Object.keys(obj);

    for (let i in obj){
        if (obj[i] > counter){
            counter = obj[i]
        }
    }

    str = keys[counter - 1];

    return str;
}

console.log(
    findMostCommon(strings)
)
```

Comment: `reduce` callback should `return`. Whatever is returned is passed on the next iteration as the first argument.

Comment: @zerkms Oh right. Duh. That's embarrassing. Thank you.

Comment: Don't comment out the part of the question that you're asking about. The SO code formatted dims it, making it hard to read.

Comment: @Barmar Okay should I have commented out the for loop or just removed it entirely?

Comment: You should post the minimal code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `reduce`, the value you get as the previous is whatever you returned in the last iteration. So:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].reduce(function(sumSoFar, currentNumber){
    return sumSoFar + currentNumber; // whatever I return here is the next value
}, 0);
```

The correct way to use reduce here, would be to add a property to the object *and return it*.

```
arr.reduce((obj, val, ind, arr) => {
    obj[arr[ind]] = (obj[arr[ind]] || 0) + 1; // arr[ind] is just val btw
    return obj; // LOOK AT ME
}, obj);
```

Of course, this gets nicer with newer ES features:

```
arr.reduce((obj, val) => {
    return {...obj, [val] : (obj[val] || 0) + 1 }
}, {});
```

Note that the latter version (or with Object.assign if you're ES2015 limited) will create a new object on each turn. For thousands of objects that might be a problem.

With lodash, that's just `_.countBy(arr)` by the way :)